# Usage of semi colon at the termination of for loop

Tags: for-loop

Is it possible to add a semicolon at the close brace of a for loop? For example `for(i=0;i<n;i++){};` Will it work? If so,how is it working?

Comment: Tag your language, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the language.

I cannot think of any language which would require it, nor can I think of any language with which it would cause a problem.  They treat it as an empty statement and is optimized out.

Comment: It will work, in that it won't break. It's roughly the equivalent of adding an empty comment. I have seen hundreds of semi-colons added to source code to bolster line counts. Those semi-colons do not affect the software at all.